# How i can send data variable to multiple activity at the same time?

Tags: android, start-activity

```
      String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
        String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(DeviceList.this, MainActivity.class);
         intent1.putExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS, address); 
          startActivity(intent1);
        Intent intent12 = new Intent(DeviceList.this, Room1.class);
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS, address);
```

how i can send the same data at the same time using intent to multiple activity  without start this activity ?

Comment: I think there is no purpose to do that, In this case you should use SharedPreferences take look here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

Comment: what is your research?

Comment: You can't and there is no need of that. Can you explain what you try to achieve and show what you've tried so far?